# Troubleshooting SQL Error in creating a table

Tags: sql-server

I have the code:

```
USE pricingdb
go
CREATE TABLE dbo.Fin_Options_Specs (
    column1 NVARCHAR(255),
    column2 NVARCHAR(255),
    column3 DOUBLE
    );
Go
```

And I'm trying to create a 3-column table using SQL.  The names of the columns will be changed later, and that isn't the issue.  However, I keep getting the error

> "Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Comment: Please specify the sql environment you are working with??

Comment: double is typically not a datatype; try `numeric(10,3)` or `float`

Comment: @Andomar: double is a valid datatype for Postgres

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no datatype of `DOUBLE`.  You probably want a `Numeric(18, 5)` or another one like `float`.

[MSDN DataTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: @user1428692 if this answer is helpful, then consider accepting it via the checkmark on the left.